# How to query for All Pallets StorageVersions

Tags: pallet, storage, rpc, json-rpc

Is there an easy way to get a list of all pallets storage versions? An output like this:
[
Palletname, StorageVersion
]

Is it possible to query using curl and the rpc for the storage version of all pallets or does anyone have some commandline fu that can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Getting the pallet version from [`polkadot-js-api`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/8ba4ed53776a7a71478e229547c7af3d4dc57d63/packages/types/src/metadata/decorate/storage/index.spec.ts#L51) is as simple as:

```
await api.query.system.palletVersion()
```

You can wrap this in a script to give you all of the pallet versions:

Comment: this is the palletversion, the storageVersion was the one i was looking for

Comment: what do you exactly mean by storageVersion? is it something standard that all pallets have?

Answer (score 0):

the way to do it with js is to loop the pallets and query storageVersion and validate the returned payload:

```js
api.query.$pallet.storageVersion
```